# 'ServerEvents.NotifySession' method not working since update to ServiceStack 5.8.0

Tags: servicestack

Since I upgraded to ServiceStack 5.8.0, the method IServerEvents.NotifySession has stopped working. I am wondering if this is because I was using the method in some incorrect way that is no longer supported by ServiceStack?

When a sessionId is available, following is how I want to notify the specific client that a value has changed:

**This used to work, but no longer does:**

```
ServerEvents.NotifySession(sessionId, null, response, channel: CNCUpdateChannel);
```

When a sessionId is not available, I use the following to notify all clients

**This still works:**

```
ServerEvents.NotifyChannel(CNCUpdateChannel, response);
```

Has anyone else experienced this, or is it just me doing something wrong?

Comment: I got around this problem by looking up the subscription ID associated with the session ID (by using the GetAllSubscriptionInfos method on the IServerEvents object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing's changed with the Session API, if you're not going to specify a Selector you should use the API overload that doesn't specify a selector (so it uses an implicit selector), e.g:

```
ServerEvents.NotifySession(sessionId, response, CNCUpdateChannel);
```

Otherwise the SessionId you should be using is the id returned by `IRequest.GetSessionId()`.

Comment: Thank you @mythz. This is an extension method (on IServerEvents) that I had completely missed. (May be its new in 5.8.0?) After using this method, NotifySession is working. Thanks again!

Comment: @yog glad it's resolved. not new, every IServerEvents Notify API has the same extension method overloads available which were [added in 2014](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/790a5eead16ae27fcf006e4c83752ecda3081755).